# How do I hide my location in Yelp?

Tags: privacy, yelp.com

After making a Yelp account, I discovered that my hometown was displayed publicly on my account profile. I tried to remove my location in account settings to protect my privacy, but Yelp will not let me delete my primary location.

How do I hide my hometown from my Yelp profile?

Answer (score 1):

- in Yelp you can't hide your selected location, however, you can hide yourself in one of thousand different cities or countries which is from the privacy point of view as good as to be hidden
- go to **https://www.yelp.ie/profile_location**
- click on the edit button

  [image: 0]
- select your fake residence and save

  [image: 0]

  [image: 0]